# Prove $\forall p \in \mathbb R \; :\; p \gt 0, \; \lim \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Prove $\forall p \in \mathbb R \; :\; p \gt 0, \; \lim \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}=0$

So I'm very new to analysis and proofs in general, so I'm sure I did this incorrectly but here is my attempt:

Suppose $\epsilon$ is any positive real number

We want to find $N$ such that if $n>N$, $\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}-0\right| \lt \epsilon$

Since $\left|(-1)^n\right|$ is bounded by $1$, we know $\left|(-1)^n\right| \le 1$ and assuming $n \rightarrow \infty$ we can rewrite the equation like so:

$\frac{\left|(-1)^n\right|}{\left|n^p\right|} \le \frac{1}{n^p} \lt \epsilon$

If we solve for $n$ we get $\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{\epsilon}} \lt n$ or $N =\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$

Am I on the right track or is this way off?

Comment: You want $N = \left[\epsilon^{-1/p}\right] + 1$ just to make sure it's an integer.

Comment: @AdamHughes I could be missing something simple, but where does the $+1$ come from?

Comment: the floor function decreases the value, so if you don't add $1$, you'll be below the threshhold.

Comment: @AdamHughes got it!  So everything else looks OK?  If so I'm very proud of myself haha!

Comment: You can be slightly stronger.  |$(-1)^n $| = 1, exactly.  No possibility of less than.

Comment: @free_mind yep, you basically did this one all on your own! And I approve your use of $|(-1)^n|\le 1$, that's a good way to think about things in general. Equality holds, but in analysis $\le$ is king.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of how to find the $N$ is correct. Here is how you might actually write up the proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $N=\left[\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\right] + 1$. Then, for all $n\geq N$, we have

$$
\bigg|\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{p}}-0\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{p}}\bigg|=\frac{1}{n^{p}}<\frac{1}{N^{p}}=\frac{1}{\left(\left[\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\right] + 1\right)^{p}}\leq\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\right)^{p}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon.
$$

Remember, you don't want to include your rough work (finding the right $N$) in your actual proof; you should just show your $N$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate proof: 
$$-\frac{1}{n^p}\le \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\le \frac{1}{n^p},$$
for $n,p>0$
Both lower and upper bound converge to zero and thus the convergence holds.